# VLookUp for Only Colour in Cells?

Tags: excel, vba, colors, vlookup, cells

I have a question. How do I use the VLookUp feature to transfer colours and not values. For example if I have a row with the row name as 'colours' on column A and I input different cell colours in the same row, from columns B- E . How do I make it that if I type 'colours' somewhere else, I want the same sequence of colours to follow it. In other words, VLookUp usually does that for values. But how do I do it for colours? The thing is that there are many rows like that. not just one row 'colours'.. but like 'colours 1', 'colours 2'. so I need it to recognize from what I input and give me the corresponding colours

Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: no but the thing is that there are many rows like that. not just one row 'colours'.. but like 'colours 1', 'colours 2'. so I need it to recognize from what I input and give me the corresponding colours

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge there is no way to do this on the fly. You'll have to apply conditional formatting to all the cells (which wont be worth it) or use a macro. Depending on your VBA experience I would ask, are the colors of the cells all that important? Would it be too tedious to just set the whole spreadsheet up at once, or does it contain too much changing data?

Comment: Yes it is important and it does contain too much changing data :(

Comment: If you can add some VBA tags some of those specialists will help. I'm [not good with/never bothered to learn] VBA, but I do know that its relatively simple if you're good at understanding coding languages.